# Code Highlightning

Tags: feature-request

Can we get proper syntax highlighting for the few coding languages that are likely to be discussed here, as is the case on Stackoverflow?

I guess that list mostly constitutes

- R
- Python
- Matlab
- STATA (dont know if there's actually syntax highlighting for that over on stackoverflow

Answer (score 3):

From [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting) it seems like we don't need to request this. It should suffice to tag the question with the appropriate language. R, Python, and Matlab are all supported.

I expect that we will struggle to get Stata highlighting because there is no support for this language in the underlying engine being used to do the syntax highlighting.

Comment: You mean to tag the tag with the proper language, rather? We can see whether it works based on this question: http://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/6606/forecast-of-arma-garch-model-in-r

Comment: @FooBar Yes, having re-read the page I see that one has to "tag the tag" to let SE know which language the tag refers to. But I can't figure out how to introduce such a code hint.

Comment: I asked about how to do this at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261175/adding-a-language-hint-to-a-tag-for-syntax-highlighting